# How to delete a button using PYQT4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I am trying to delete this button

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Log in", self)
btn.clicked.connect(self.remove)
```

When the button is clicked, it should disappear,but this doesn't work

```
btn.deleteQPushButton()
```

Or if there's any way to entirely delete every button in the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elegant solution is to use [`deleteLater()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater):

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Log in", self)
btn.clicked.connect(btn.deleteLater)
```

Comment: Perfect! Works easily - Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Yep, use deleteLater

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    wMain = QWidget()
    wMain.resize(250, 150)
    wMain.setWindowTitle('Main')
    wMain.show()

    centralLayout = QHBoxLayout(wMain)
    wMain.setLayout(centralLayout)

    button = QPushButton('Delete me',wMain)
    button.clicked.connect(button.deleteLater)
    centralLayout.addWidget(button)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What difference does your answer have with mine?

Comment: I recommend reading the following before answering.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer